# Pyautogui error when locating image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, location, pyautogui

I am using this library `pyautogui` and I am trying to locate image:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.locateOnScreen("test.png")
```

But every time except if it doesn't find it it gives me this error:

`Pyautogui` throws the below Error

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.